# ui-grid: separate headerTemplate for pinned column and main grid

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using `ui-grid` 3 together with the default `ui.grid.pinning` plugin. My grid has a config similar to this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
      enableSorting: true,
      headerTemplate: 'views/report-header.html',
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'firstName', displayName: 'First Name', width: 120, pinnedLeft: true },
        { field: 'lastName', displayName: 'Last Name', width: 120 },
        { field: 'company', displayName: 'Company', width: 120 },
      ]
    }
```

This correctly results in the `firstName` column being pinned. However, it also results in the custom `headerTemplate` view (which is just `<div>I am unique!</div>` in this case) being set for **both** the pinned column and main grid to the left of it:

[image]

Is there any way to specify which header should be set for the pinned column, and which should be set for the main grid?

Comment: this might be helpful - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/644

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up defining separate templates (`pinnedGridTemplate.html` and `mainGridTemplate.html`, respectively), and assigned these to the columns that were supposed to go into either section. The definition above then becomes:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableSorting: true,
      columnDefs: [
        {
          field: 'firstName',
          displayName: 'First Name',
          width: 120,
          pinnedLeft: true,
          headerTemplate: 'views/pinnedGridTemplate.html'
        },
        {
          field: 'lastName',
          displayName: 'Last Name',
          width: 120,
          headerTemplate: 'views/mainGridTemplate.html'
        },
        {
          field: 'company',
          displayName: 'Company',
          width: 120,
          headerTemplate: 'views/mainGridTemplate.html'
        },
      ]
    }
```